# Error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, android

I keep getting this error with my JavaScript command I am trying to run through my WebView in Android Studio.

I have JavaScript and DomStorage enabled.

Code:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function("+
                    "l=document.getElementById('form-login-submit');"+
                    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
                    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
                    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
                    "))()");
                //"l= document.querySelector('#login-form [type="+'"'+"submit"+'"'+"]');"+
```

I also tried to use the out commented line but got the same error.

Can someone help me fix this error?

Comment: missing `){` and the end of the function block `}`

Comment: @Hacketo thanks that was the anwser!